# Failed to execute gl.texSubImage2d

Tags: 3d, html5-canvas, gpu, webgl

I'm trying to load data from a GPU resident buffer into a texture in WebGL2 on Chrome.  I would like to avoid copying data in and out of the GPU if possible.

I'm trying to use the following calling sequence

```
// WebGL 2:
void gl.texSubImage2D(target, level, xoffset, yoffset, format, type, GLintptr offset);
```

Documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D -- but I always get

```
Failed to execute 'texSubImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Here is more information on the set up for the call:

```
            var target = gl.TEXTURE_2D;
            var level = 0;
            var xoffset = 0;
            var yoffset = 0;
            //var height = this.height;
            //var width = this.width;
            var format = gl[this.format];
            var gl_type = gl[this.typ];
            //var srcData = array;
            //var srcData = 0;
            //var srcOffset = 0;
            var offset = 0;
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D
            gl.bindTexture(target, this.gl_texture);
            // ERRORS:
            gl.texSubImage2D(target, level, xoffset, yoffset, format, gl_type, offset);
```

In very similar code the following calling sequence (copying from an array buffer) works fine.

```
            gl.texSubImage2D(target, level, xoffset, yoffset, width, height, format, gl_type, srcData, srcOffset);
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?  As far as I can tell all the arguments are valid (but I know webGL error messages are often misleading).  Is there any example code using the above 7 argument calling sequence which works?  I haven't found any examples.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN is wrong. There is no function

```
void gl.texSubImage2D(target, level, xoffset, yoffset, format, type, GLintptr offset);
```

See the actual spec:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/

You can't very well have a "tex**Sub**Image2D" function that doesn't some how take a width and a height one way or another.

I edited the MDN article to fix that function signature